# Javascript cloning elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<body>
<div>
    <p id="test"></p>
</div>
<script>
    //  I'm trying to clone an element
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1'); // I create <h1>
    h1.innerHTML('test'); // I put some text between this element <h1>test</h1>
    document.getElementById('test').appendChild(h1); // I add this h1 to <p id="test"><h1>test</h>
    var h1Clone = h1.cloneNode(true); // I use cloneNode to clone h1

    // Here I'll clone the <p> tag and add h1Clone to it
    var paragraph = document.getElementById('test'); // Look for id="test"
    paragraph.appendChild(h1); // Add h1 as <p>'s child
    var paragraphClone = paragraph.cloneNode(true); // Clone <p>
    paragraphClone.appendChild(h1Clone); // Add h1Clone as <p>'s (clone) child.

    paragraph.parentNode.appendChild(paragraphClone); // Finally I add <p>'s clone to <body> tag
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello, I commented everything so you can understand what I'm trying to do..
Why can't I make it working?

Here is the final html result that I'm trying to have:

```
<p id="test"><h1>test</h1></p>
<p id="test"><h1>test</h1></p> <-- clone ->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `h1.innerHTML = 'test';` instead of `h1.innerHTML('test')`

Answer (score 2):

#### If you can use jQuery, it is very easy:

**Step 1:** Add the jQuery library. In the `<head>` section, add this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Step 2:** Inside your `<script>` tags in the `<body>` section, instead of your code, give this:

```
$("#test").clone().appendTo("div");
```

As simple as that.

#### Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/GeQpH/